# Expression Trees and Joins

Tags: .net, linq, expression-trees, dynamic-linq

```
Expression<Func<Account, IEnumerable<Attachment>>> attachments =  t => attachmentBuilder.Populate("COMPANYNAME", t.AccountID.ToString());

 var q = cxt.Accounts.Select(e => new
 {
    AccountID = e.AccountID,
        Description = e.AccountDescription,
 });
```

What I ideally want is to Join attachments Expression (results) to q (accounts- IEnumerable)
so I can filter by AccountID which is dynamically passed from UI "t.AccountID.ToString()"
I dont want to use sub query as I have loads of attachments so I am looking for a more Join type solution with Dynamic Linq and Expression trees with passing the account id dynamically.
Thanks,

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking. Maybe an example of what the final expression should look like would help.

Comment: @svick In a normal case say I have an attachments table and a accounts table, I can make a straight forward join on say acctionid column and do a where accountid on the query to get the account with all attachments associated with it filtered by accountid passed.

Comment: @svick The problem I have having is I have a business object method which returns attachments for an account attachmentBuilder.Populate passes company which is hardcoded for simplicity and accountid passed dynamically. As accountid is not know till its passed I need a join between the return of this method and the accounts collection filtered by accountid passed. Dont ask me why as I am told to do it this way..I know it sounds very crazy